# (change) not working with select2 in angular 5

Tags: angular5, jquery-select2

The (change) directive is working fine with normal select html tag in angular 5. But if I implement select2 plugin, then (change) won't work.

Here is my html file

```
<select class="select2Select" [(ngModel)]="productSearchItem" (ngModelChange)="test()">
  <option value="">Search entire store here...</option>
  <option *ngFor="let product of products" value="{{ product.pid }}">{{ product.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Here is the function doing nothing just consoling something in typescript

```
test(){
    console.log("Hi");
}
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select2Select').select2();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the change event using `jquery` inside the lifecycle hook:

```
ngOnInit() {
  $('.select2Select').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    console.log("Hi");
  });
}
```